# How should I programmatically update constraints for a dynamic view?

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints

I want to know the best practice for updating views/constraints to have a dynamic view with multiple possible (visible) subviews. In this simple example, let's say I want a **custom** `UITableViewCell` with the possibility of two 'states', one with a header and a body label, and one with only the body label, like the images below. **Important**: I am not looking for a way to create these exact two states, this is just an example. I know that a regular cell has `subtitle` which would achieve this, but my real problem is way more complex.

First state:

[image: First state]

Second state:

[image: Second state]

One option would be to create these two cells as separate cells, but I want to find out if there's any 'accepted' way to make a single cell (the first one) and have it display in various states - preferably without having to handle **a ton** of programmatic states.

First of all, I assume that both labels has to be constrained to the top-margin of the cell itself. If I don't do this, both states won't be possible, right? Or is there another way to get the second state from the first view?

How should the constraints be set up, and how should I handle them in code - to achieve a single view with different layouts?

Comment: how about using `UIStackView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack views can help you solve this problem. They automatically adjust their intrinsic size if you hide one of their arranged subviews, so in your example above you would have both labels in a stack view, and use constraints to pin the stack view to the cell.

If you hide the header label, the body text label will move into the correct position (depending on the settings in your stack view).

If you're using autosizing cells and you're basing the cell height from your stack view, then the cells will adjust their height correctly as well.

Stack views are a great solution to the otherwise complex problem of having optional views that require other views to adjust their positions.

Comment: Damnit! Beat me by less than a minute :-P

Comment: Great! I never read up on `UIStackView`, because we have always been supporting down to iOS 7 on this project - until a week ago when we decided to drop both iOS 7 **and** iOS 8 (`UIStackView` is only available on iOS 9+). It didn't occur to me to check all the new API's I can use after dropping 7/8. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way of changing between these two different states is to use a `UIStackView`. (`UIStackView` should also be your default tool for creating layouts anyway).

Create a vertical stack view that arranges your `headerLabel` and `bodyLabel`.

Set the `layoutMargins` of the stack view and the `spacing` to suit what you need.

Then to change between the two you just need to set `isHidden` on the `headerLabel`.

The stack view will then do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using StackViews which might certainly be the best option in some cases (I honestly don't know) I want to give an alternative using constraints:

I would do it the following way. Assuming the one with the bold text is called **big** and the other one is called **small**:

- Add one constraint of **small** to the top (C1)
- Add one constraint of **small** to **big** (C2)
- Add one constraint of **big** to the top (C3)
- In state one have **big** visible, C2 and C3 enabled, C1 disabled
- In state two have **big** invisible, C1 and C3 enabled, C2 disabled.

For this to work you need to have the labels and C1 and C2 connected to your code via outlets.